# Listing Coin Toss Possibilities

Tags: c#

Good day to all. I'm learning programming and I'm trying to put in a list of strings all possible outcomes of a series of coin tosses and while the code below works for small number of coin tosses (<20, I get out of memory exception), I want something that could handle higher numbers (possibly around 40).

I tried searching for similar problems with solution but nothing seems to catch my eye or at my level.

Can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong or nudge me in the right direction?

```
public static class CoinToss {
    private const int numberTosses = 11;

    private static List<string> allPossibilities = new List<string>();

    public static void WriteAllPossibilities() {
        List<string> temp = new List<string>(); ;

        allPossibilities.Add("H");
        allPossibilities.Add("T");

        int tossIndex = 1;
        while (tossIndex++ < numberTosses) {
            /* Clear the temporary */
            temp.Clear();

            foreach (string outcome in allPossibilities) {
                temp.Add(outcome + "H");
                temp.Add(outcome + "T");
            }

            /* Remove all items in all possibilities */
            allPossibilities.Clear();

            /* Copy allPaths from temp */
            foreach (string path in temp) {
                allPossibilities.Add(path);
            }
        }

        foreach (string path in allPossibilities) {
            Console.WriteLine(path);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(allPossibilities.Count);

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming you are calling this from a Console App?

Comment: You can't keep them all in memory, 40 coins means 2^40 possible outcomes. If you were to simply store them all as 5-byte (40 bit) values, this is still 2^40*5 bytes of memory, which is 5TB.

Comment: However, you don't need to store them, since you're dealing with coins that can have only two states, you can use any ordinary 40-bit number for this, so simply count a `long` from 0 up to 2^40, and convert 0's to head and 1's to tail, and you got all your combinations. But still, you can't keep them all in memory.

Comment: Or, if you simply printed each combination to the console as you find it.

Comment: To expand on @Lasse's comment, note that you can represent all 2^40 possibilities with 40 bits of information. A 64-bit integer (i.e. a `long` or `ulong`) would be large enough to contain that. So your problem really decomposes to iteration from 0 to 2^40-1, and converting the integer to binary, where you display `H` and `T` instead of `0` and `1`. There is, of course the question of where you're going to find a user with the patience to read all 2^40 combinations...but that's a different issue.

Comment: Yes I'm calling it from a console app.

Comment: Ok ill try doing it bitwise.

Comment: I need to process the list afterwards thats why I'm keeping it in a list.

Comment: Wow 5TB. I have to rethink my approach then. Thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 2):

I am surprised that there's not an example of this problem, among all the "coin flip" questions already on Stack Overflow. But, I couldn't find a suitable duplicate. You may be the first to post a question about this specific issue in the specific context of coin flips.

In a comment, [you wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44094522/c-sharp-listing-coin-toss-possibilities#comment75210545_44094522):

> I need to process the list afterwards thats why I'm keeping it in a list

That is never going to work. As has been pointed out in the comments, to represent all possible combinations of 40 coin flips will require 2^40 different sequences. Even if you're conservative and store them in a packed data structure five bytes at a time, that's still 2^40 times five bytes of memory, which is nearly 5-1/2 terabytes. That is technically within the limits of a 64-bit process, but not within any reasonable practical limits in terms of what Windows or a typical computer running Windows will provide.

Furthermore, even if you could store all those sequences, it would take an exceptional amount of time to do anything useful with them. And no human would be able to read fast enough to see the entire list; assuming they are super-fast readers and can read 10 per second, that's still 17,000 years.

That said, the basic logic to generate them is easy enough, even if there's not enough time for the program to complete. One approach would look something like this:

```
class Program
{
    const int flipCount = 40;
    const long counterMax = (long)1 << flipCount;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (long flipSequence = 0; flipSequence < counterMax; flipSequence++)
        {
            DisplayFlips(flipSequence);
        }
    }

    private static readonly StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(flipCount);

    private static void DisplayFlips(long flipSequence)
    {
        sb.Clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < flipCount; i++)
        {
            sb.Append((flipSequence & 1) != 0 ? 'T' : 'H');
            flipSequence >>= 1;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(sb);
    }
}
```